# @media queries and regular css interactions

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a side panel that has a `position:fixed` on my page.
In the css, the following @media query to hide the panel if the screen width is below 1580px (which is most screens).

```
@media screen and (max-width:1580px) {
  .sideSection {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I have created a hidden checkbox and a label to click, to show the panel over the screen, using

```
<input type="checkbox" name="showSide" id="showSideSection"/>
<label for="showSideSection" id="sideSectionButton">Show Side Section</label>
<div class="sideSection">
[...]
```

and in the css :

```
#showSideSection:checked + label + div {
  display: inline;
}
```

This works perfectly theoretically, but since the @media is dynamic, it will always hide the side panel. Is there a way to have the @media query check if `#showSideSection` is `:checked`; or any better way overall to have the panel show on screens with a width > 1580, and be replaced with a button which would show said panel when clicked on screens with a width < 1580?

Edit : This is the css for the sideSection :

```
.sideSection {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 180px;
  height:calc(100% - 180px);
  width: 230px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #ededed;
  border-left: 5px solid #e33d3d;
}
```

Comment: Why would you create a hidden checkbox? That's so wrong / hackish.

Comment: @JosipIvic I use the :checked state to do stuff in the CSS, but I don't want an ugly checkbox to show in the middle of my page...

Comment: can show me your exactly layout.

Comment: @Fiido93 I've updated the question with the css for the side section

Comment: This: `#showSideSection:checked + label + div` have more specificity than `.sideSection` alone, so it must work with your exact code. You can see it working: https://jsfiddle.net/xhe96kqr/ . So if you want that we help you, you must to provide a working example reproducing the issue. Please, read more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See the snippet updated to a minimum value (max-width 400px)  https://jsfiddle.net/xhe96kqr/2/

Answer (score 0):

This cant be acheived with pure css, your best bet would be to create another class for showing the panel and then use javascript to add this class to the sidebar if the checkbox is checked.

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
if(this.checked){
     $('#Section').addClass('checked');
}
else {
     //do something else
     $('#Section').removeClass('checked');
}
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9UQf8/22/

Comment: And in the case of Javascript vs media queries, which one supercedes the other ? I think if I use js to show the panel and media queries to hide it, the problem kind of remains... Would it be better to ditch media queries and use javascript to detect screen width and change it this way too ?

Comment: Use the media queries as you are - but create a new class outside the media query to show the panel - then use JS to add this class to the element when the box is checked

Comment: @Saryk I have updated my answer with a JS fiddle (using Jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work thanks to this https://jsfiddle.net/xhe96kqr/2/, courtesy of [Marcos Pérez Gude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5035890/marcos-p%C3%A9rez-gude), whom I thank.
Not using anything other than css and @Media Queries:

```
#showSideSection:checked + label + div {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
  .sideSection {
    display: none ;
  }
}
```

Comment: it should be display:block not inline.